# alasql compatibility with IE8

Tags: javascript, excel, internet-explorer-8, alasql

I was trying to implement a project using alasql in an IE8 environment but keep getting the same error. The alasql function isnt executing properly. 
I get the following error-

Expected identifier
File: alasql.min.js, Line: 7, Column: 9848

i get this error even when trying to run the most basic code possible which is given below -

```
var res = alasql('select * from xlsx("xlsxURL")',[],function(res){
            console.log(res[1])
});
```

Is there any way to make it IE8 compliant  ?

Comment: Sorry, I affraid no. The reason that IE8 does not support functions which AlaSQL uses for binary files. If you find the binary file reading procedure for IE8, please send it to us, and we will include it into the library.

Comment: Is there any other way i could export the contents of the excel sheet into an array using javascript or even other languages that supports ie8 ?